# How to look up a method within the compiler given the type and a name?

Tags: rust, lint

I have a lint that warns on `x.len() == 0`, suggesting to use `x.is_empty()` instead. However, I wanted to get rid of the false positives if `x` has no `is_empty(self: &Self)` method.

Thus began the quest to look up methods from within rustc.

First step, get the `x`: I matched the `node` of an `Expr` to `ExprMethodCall(ref method, _, ref args)` (and made sure that `args.len() == 1` and `method.node.as_str() == "len"`) and just used `&*args[0]`, which I will call `expr` from now on.

Next step, get the type of `x`: This can easily be done using `rustc::middle::ty::expr_ty(cx.tcx, expr)`. Note that this is a `rustc::middle::ty::Ty` (and not a `syntax::ast::Ty`, which led to some confusion).

To look up the methods, the `ctxt.impl_items` and `ctxt.trait_item_def_ids` looked promising, so I get the `DefId` for my type with `rustc::middle::ty::ty::ty_to_def_id(ty)` and try to get the ids. However, this approach has a few problems:

For

```
let x = [1, 2];
x.len() == 2 // <- lookee here
```

I simply have no DefId. That is ok though, because we have a `ty_vec` in that case, and `std::vec::Vec` is known to have both `len()` and `is_empty()`.

The good message is that the `ctxt.trait_item_def_ids` *has* a suitable entry for a trait with a `is_empty` method. Alas, for the following example:

```
struct One;
impl One { fn is_empty(self: &Self) -> bool { false } }
```

I got no `TraitOrItemId` for any impl item, which is a bit unfortunate. Can someone privy to rustc help me find my impl items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it! The problem was that I trying to get a DefId for the *type*, not for the `impl`. Going through `cx.tcx.inherent_impls.get(id)` gave me a vec of `DefId`s for inherent impls, which I could then query via the `impl_items` lookup I already implemented.

Look in [rust-clippy/src/len_zero.rs](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/blob/7f5891184d55c3d01f57cf480d718e19f9f8268d/src/len_zero.rs#L119) for an example implementation. Edit: Note that the implementation is *O(N)* where *N* is the number of methods of the type (either direct `impl` or by traits) – perhaps rustc will someday allow a faster lookup...